# Get CSS scale transform to change the vertical scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to zoom in or out into an element using the CSS scale transform. I can scale properly. However, *only the horizontal scroll-bar* is affected by the transform. The vertical scroll-bar is not.

I know that CSS transforms should not affect element sizes. Obviously, they *do* affect element sizes and layouts - but only horizontally.

Here's an example that demonstrates this:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: orange;
}

p {
  font-size: 50em;
  margin: 0px;
  transform: scale(1.0);  /* Change to scale(0.2) to see the horizontal scroll bar disppear */
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>LargeText</p>
</div>
```

Change the scale to 0.2 and see how the horizontal scroll bar properly disappears, while the vertical one does not.

How can I get the browser to remove the vertical scroll bar if it's unnecessary, just like it does with the horizontal scrollbar?

I tested this with Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, it appears to you that changing the scale of the text causes the overflow to take effect only in horizontal dimension, but not in the vertical dimension. This is not the case, both in this case are treated equally, but the exact values you have chosen for your example obscure the actual behavior.

I have modified the example you posted so it is easy to interactively play with the scaling factor:

```css
.wrapper {
  --scale: 1.0;
  background: orange;
}

p {
  font-size: 7.5em;
  margin: 0px;
  transform: scale(var(--scale));  /* Change to scale(0.2) to see the horizontal scroll bar disppear */
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="scale" min="0.05" value="1" max="4" step="0.05" oninput="document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.setProperty('--scale', this.value)">
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>LongText</p>
</div>
```

In the default sizing of stackoverflow snippet, the `<p>` element fits to height and width, so no scrollbars appear:

[image: default scaling]

Increasing the scale results in overflow in both directions:

[image: bigger scaling with overflow]

What you are seeing in your example, is the vertical overflow always happening, because of the height of the `<p>` element, which is `50em`:

[image: vertical overflow]

Because the `transform: scale()` rule does not decrease the intrinsic size of the paragraph, it will always be at least `50em`, almost always causing a vertical overflow.

As for using this knowledge to solve your problem, I would recommend starting with a default `auto` size and use `scale > 1` for zoom-in, and not the other way around.